# div id "wrapper" not running in box model

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I created an id wrapper in CSS:

```
#wrapper {
    position: relative;
    background: yellow;
    -webkit-box-shadow:  0px 0px 6px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    box-shadow:  0px 0px 6px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    width: 960px;
    padding: 40px 35px 35px 35px;
    margin: 0px auto;
}
```

class box in CSS:

```
float: left;
width: 170px;
height: 190px;
margin: 10px;
border: 3px solid #8AC007; 
border-radius: 5px;
right: auto;
```

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper"><div class="box">
    <a href="#"><p>ini box 1</p></a>    
</div> </div>
```

The problem is the box is out from the wrapper. What is the soultion?

Answer (score 3):

Remove the float:left style from box css

```
.box {
    width: 170px;
    height: 190px;
    margin: 10px;
    border: 3px solid #8AC007;
    border-radius: 5px;
    right: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `overflow: auto` to wrapper to clear the float of box.

Comment: thank you, i forget to add overflow: auto, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I always recommend a clearing element after floats, old IE especially behaved unpredictably without them

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="box">
        <a href="#"><p>ini box 1</p></a>    
    </div>
    <div class='clr'></div>
</div>
```

additional CSS

```
.clr {
    clear:both;
    height:0px;
}
```